# Bash quote problems

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, cygwin, quotes

I'm trying to invoke a native Windows command from Cygwin using `run`, but as it happens, the command (which I'm taking from the registry) is already quoted and in several parts:

```
"C:\path\to\file.exe" -- "some argument"
```

If I use `run "C:\path\to\file.exe" -- "some argument"` from the terminal, it works fine, but as soon as I put it in a Bash script it tries to escape the double quotes <s>and adds single quotes around the entire thing</s>, which ruins it:

```
\"C:\path\to\file.exe\" -- \"some argument\"
```

If I put an `echo` in before trying to run the command, it displays the expected command, but the `run` command fails.

```
echo $command
run $command
```

I'm fairly new to bash scripting, so I expect I'm missing something fundamental :)

**Update**: I think I got confused about the single quotes.

**Update**: Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
command=`cat /proc/registry/hkey_classes_root/http/shell/open/command/@`
command=${command/"%1"/$target}
run $command
```

Here's what I've tried in response to SiegeX's suggestion:

```
command=`cat /proc/registry/hkey_classes_root/http/shell/open/command/@`
command=(${command/"%1"/$target})
run "${command[@]}"
```

I've also tried `cmd /c` as an alternative to `run`, with the same results (works from the terminal but not the script).

Comment: Urgh… Cygwin tries for UNIX-compatible argument handling (`char **argv`), but Windows' model is completely different (`LPCWSTR lpCmdLine`) and different Windows programs will interpret the command line differently.  What is the particular command program you're trying to run?

Comment: It's Chrome. The full command is `"C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "<some URL>"`.

Comment: Is the output of `cat /proc/registry/hkey_classes_root/http/shell/open/command/@` literally `"C:\path\to\file.exe" -- "some argument"` with quotes and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
command=$(< /proc/registry/hkey_classes_root/http/shell/open/command/@)
command=${command//\"/}
command=$(cygpath "$command")
command=${command/\%1/$target}
eval run $command
```

Comment: Dennis, why do these two lines give different results? `arr=("C:\path\to\file.exe" -- "some argument"); echo ${arr[2]}` vs `arr=($(echo '"C:\path\to\file.exe" -- "some argument"')); echo ${arr[2]}`. I get `some argument` in the former and `"some` in the latter.

Comment: @Siegex: In the first example, the shell splits on white space then drops the quotes. In your second example, the single quotes make the everything one long string with the double quotes as characters within it. So it's split on the white space then the *single* quotes are dropped. The double quotes remain.

Comment: Hmm, according to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting , Word Splitting happens *after* command substitution. So, if true, shouldn't the two test cases look identical to the shell by the time Word Splitting does its thing?

Comment: @SiegeX: Command substitution, according to the [Bash Manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32), is "[performed] by executing [the] command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of  the  command". Further, "The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for [word splitting](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35)." The thing to remember is that a command substitution is itself a command. So the nested command undergoes the same sequence..

Comment: (cont.) ...of expansions in a nested fashion. Try this command to see that the word splitting within the command substitution is completed before the outer command is performed: `cat $(a=(one two);echo $a>side-effect-1; echo ${a[1]}>side-effect-2; echo "side-effect-2 side-effect-1")`. And you'll notice that word-splitting is performed on the *result* of the command substitution *after* it is performed (as you said).

Comment: Thanks, I see I can't treat it like `f(g(x))` because `"` is not just data but syntax to the shell as well.

Comment: @SiegeX: Depending on exactly how you mean it, you may be able to do the kind of thing you're talking about if proper quoting is done. Command substitution can be nested. Also, quotes inside `$()` are independent of quotes outside. In `foo "$(bar "baz $(quux "aaa bbb")")"` the quotes are evaluated inside to the outside rather than left-to-right open-close-open-close...

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One other question: I notice that this removes the quotes altogether, so would additional escaping by required if the registry key were to contain a path with spaces and such in it? The argument that replaces `%1` is either a URL or a Windows file path (from `cygpath`), so in the latter case I've had to escape the slashes manually with `target=${target//\\/\\\\}` – is this the correct approach?

Comment: @Will: You can replace the space(s) using `${var/ /\\ }` or `${var// /\\ }` but you'll have to be careful not to replace the spaces around the `--` by splitting the string, doing the replacement then reassembling the string. You may be able to use options to `cygpath` to get the Windows file path in the format you need, but the replacement you show seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Quote `$command` like this:  `run "$command"`

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=("C:\path\to\file.exe" "--" "some argument")
run "${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Neither of these seems to work, unless I've done it wrong somehow. See my update.